# How to write latitude and longitude data to R using exiftoolr

Tags: r, coordinates, jpeg, exif

I made several graphs in R 3.5.2 and saved them as JPEG files. Now I'm trying to assign Latitude and Longitude of the coordinates they represent to the metadata of each JPEG in R, so that they will appear on a map in a collection of other geotagged image files. I've seen a few solutions that use separately downloaded tools, but I would like to keep this within R if possible. I'm using Windows 7 and the exiftoolr package:

```
install.packages("exiftoolr")
library(exiftoolr)

###coordinates table
LocationNo = c(1,2,3,4)
Latitude = c(39.6, 38.2, 37.2, 36.2)
Longitude = c(-121.8, -121.4, -120.7, -119.8)
coordstable = cbind.data.frame(LocationNo, Latitude, Longitude)

###set coordinates for jpg
outgraph <- list.files(pattern = "Graph2.jpg")
Lat.arg = paste0("-GPSLatitude=",coordstable$Latitude[2])
Long.arg = paste0("-GPSLongitude=",coordstable$Longitude[2])
exif_call(args = Lat.arg, path = outgraph) #set latitude
exif_call(args = Long.arg, path = outgraph) #set longitude
```

I get the following error message after trying to set latitude:

```
Trying perl command: "" --version
Trying perl command: "perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Perl64\bin\perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Perl\bin\perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl" --version
Trying exiftool command:  -ver
Trying exiftool command: exiftool -ver
Error in configure_exiftoolr(quiet = quiet) : 
  No functioning version of Exiftool has been found. To
download and install a local version into the exiftoolr
package, try doing install_exiftool().
```

I tried using `install_exiftool()` or `exiftoolr::configure_exiftoolr()` but they both get me back to the same place. Installation appears successful but I still get the same error messages when trying to actually use the commands in the package:

```
> exiftoolr::configure_exiftoolr()
Trying perl command: "" --version
Trying perl command: "perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Perl64\bin\perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Perl\bin\perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl" --version
Trying exiftool command:  -ver
Trying exiftool command: exiftool -ver
Error in exiftoolr::configure_exiftoolr() : 
  No functioning version of Exiftool has been found. To
download and install a local version into the exiftoolr
package, try doing install_exiftool().

> install_exiftool() #says it's installing but also says downloaded 0 bytes
    Attempting to download ExifTool from https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool-11.92.zip
     [0%] Downloaded 0 bytes...
     [-2147483648%] Downloaded 0 bytes...
    Installing ExifTool in C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/library/exiftoolr/exiftool

> exif_call(args = Lat.arg, path = outgraph) #try assigning latitude again
Trying perl command: "" --version
Trying perl command: "perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Perl64\bin\perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Perl\bin\perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl" --version
Trying exiftool command:  -ver
Trying exiftool command: C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/library/exiftoolr/exiftool/win_exe/exiftool(-k).exe -ver
Trying exiftool command: exiftool -ver
Error in configure_exiftoolr(quiet = quiet) : 
  No functioning version of Exiftool has been found. To
download and install a local version into the exiftoolr
package, try doing install_exiftool().

> library(exiftoolr) #returns no messages or warnings

> exif_call(args = Lat.arg, path = outgraph)
Trying perl command: "" --version
Trying perl command: "perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Perl64\bin\perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Perl\bin\perl" --version
Trying perl command: "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl" --version
Trying exiftool command:  -ver
Trying exiftool command: C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/library/exiftoolr/exiftool/win_exe/exiftool(-k).exe -ver
Trying exiftool command: exiftool -ver
Error in configure_exiftoolr(quiet = quiet) : 
  No functioning version of Exiftool has been found. To
download and install a local version into the exiftoolr
package, try doing install_exiftool().
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `exiftoolr::configure_exiftoolr()` to your question and add the operating system you are using?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm using Windows 7. This command gets me back to the same message: `try doing install_exiftool()`. I updated the post with the full output.

Comment: Do you have a Perl installation in any of the paths it is looking? Check that and then install perl and exiftool manually. Use `exiftoolr::configure_exiftoolr()`, it it doesn't find it again, use its arguments to specify the path to perl. If you are still having issues, try setting the environment variable "ET_EXIFTOOL_PATH" to the path where exiftool is installed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have permissions to install Perl (or most things) on my work machine, but I can install R packages without needing higher approval. Is there a way to install an R Perl package?

Comment: In that case you should check out some of the other EXIF packages for R. Some of them are mentioned in the [exiftoolr readme file](https://github.com/JoshOBrien/exiftoolr/blob/master/README.md#why-another-r-package-for-reading-image-file-metadata).